# Details elements with iframes inside

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, html-tag-details

I have a web page with several *details* elements. Inside one of them there is an *iframe*. In all browsers except Firefox (either desktop or mobile) the iframe contents are displayed correctly. In Firefox they don't show up. If I move the iframe outside the details element then it is displayed in Firefox. Is this expected for Firefox or is it likely a bug?

The paragraph below has been edited to provide a simpler example.

One such page is https://cdi2tp.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/test . A closed details element labeled "Firefox bug" exhibits the problem. The analogous open on load details element, also labeled "Firefox bug", below on that page displays the iframe without problems.

Same origin restrictions on the site have been turned off temporarily without any effect.

Comment: Does the console throw any errors? Perhaps a CORS issue?

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Comment: The console does throw errors if the iframe is inside the details element. Otherwise, no. I end up needing to kill the Firefox window when trying to use the console.

Comment: All the code is on the example page.

Comment: Jeremy Harris: it is not a CORS issue; I removed Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN" from my apache configuration to no avail.